# NSMutable Array Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've this code

```
SBJsonParser *vol= [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
if (body) {
    NSArray *feeds = [vol objectWithString:body error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results = [body JSONValue];
    NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"subscriptions"];
    NSArray *list;
    NSMutableArray *sub;

    for (NSDictionary *iscrizione in subs){
        NSLog([iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"]);
        NSLog([iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"]);
        list=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"], [iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"], nil];  
        [sub addObject:list];

    }
```

But when I try to add list to the NSMutableArray the program crashes. Why?
How can I insert `[iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"]` and `[iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"]`
in a data structure?

EDIT**

```
SBJsonParser *vol= [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
if (body) {
    NSArray *feeds = [vol objectWithString:body error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results = [body JSONValue];
    NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"subscriptions"];
    NSMutableArray *sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[subs count]];
    for (NSDictionary *iscrizione in subs){

        [sub addObject:iscrizione];

    }
    NSDictionary *it=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[sub objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog([it objectForKey:@"title"]);

}
```

This is my code. But I can't understand why I cannot NSLog [it objectForKey:@"title"].

Comment: Please, provide a crash info. What error it throws?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize your NSMutableArray.

Should be

`NSMutableArray *sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[subs count]];`

Technically, you could simply allocate it with 
`NSMutableArray *sub = [[NSMutableArray array];`
as well but this could be more efficient, as you already know how many data entries there will be.

Just pay attention to memory management, you need to release it in the first case and it's autoreleased in the second case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edit my code but I have another problem! Can you explain how this happens?

Comment: NSLog expects at least one parameter, but the first one is the format object. You need to type: `NSLog(@"My object: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"key"]);`. Also, why do you create another NSDictionary from the first one, allocating even more memory?

Comment: For testing... I wan't to see if the array contains all objects... to use it later... i try        NSDictionary *it=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[sub objectAtIndex:0]];
       NSLog(@"My object: %@", [it objectForKey:@"title"]); like in your suggestion but I get this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: This just means that your array is empty and you're trying to extract an object from it (from index 0). If your array can be empty it's a good idea first that your index is in the array like `if ([array count]>=desired_index-1)`

Comment: YEs but i'm sure that it contains data! Infact If i try to do         for (NSDictionary *lol in subscriptions){
            
            NSLog([lol objectForKey:@"title"]);
            NSLog([lol objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"]);
            
        } I can get all contents

Comment: Just break to debugger at that line and check if `sub` contains data or not. `subscriptions` is another array, no?

Answer (score 0):

`sub` is not allocated memory. You can create a empty array `NSMutableArray *sub = [NSMutableArray array];` outside the if condition or have a reference maintained in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should `alloc` and `init` the MutableArray before you can use it.

```
SBJsonParser *vol= [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
if (body) {
    NSArray *feeds = [vol objectWithString:body error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results = [body JSONValue];
    NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"subscriptions"];
    NSArray *list;
    NSMutableArray *sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[subs count]];

    for (NSDictionary *iscrizione in subs){
        NSLog(@"title: %@" ,[iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"]);
        NSLog(@"htmlUrl: %@", [iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"]);
        list=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"], [iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"], nil];  
        [sub addObject:list];

    }
    // here you should add code to handle the sub array.

    // Do not forget to release the allocated array
    [sub release], sub =nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edit my code but I have another problem! Can you explain how this happens? –

Comment: I've fixed te NSLog statements as `Jacob Gorban` suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Following will do work properly...

```
    NSMutableArray *sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *iscrizione in subs)
    {
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [iscrizione objectForKey:@"title"]];
        NSString *htmlURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[iscrizione objectForKey:@"htmlUrl"]];
        list=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:title, htmlURL, nil];  
        [sub addObject:list mutableCopy];
    }
```